# How can I show the photos I took from api in my vue js project in col?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vuetify.js

I am showing the data in for in my project that I created with vue js. Finally, I want to add product photos in the form. I tried as below but no result. I didn't get any errors either, which I can share. Any ideas how I can fix this or do it differently?

```
                    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3" class="d-flex child-flex" :items="products.items"  >
                     <span 
                     >Photos: </span>
                    <v-card slot="item" slot-scope="props"
                    class="mx-auto"
                    style="width: 200px; height: 200px; " 
                    >  
                      <v-img :src="props.image.url"
                      ></v-img>
                    </v-card>

                    </v-col>
```

fetch data

```
fetch('example/products')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
   
    this.products = data;
  });
```

These are the data from the API.

```
  "items": [
{
  
  "id": 60,
  "brand": {
    "name": "Samsung"
  },
  "productImages": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "image": {
        "url": "example.com"
      }
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `v-for` loop:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{"id": 60, "brand": {"name": "Samsung"}, 
        "productImages": [{"id": 1, "image": {"url": "https://picsum.photos/200"}},{"id": 2, "image": {"url": "https://picsum.photos/200"}}]}],
    }
  }
})
```

```css
slot="item" slot-scope="props"
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
      <span>Photos: </span>
      <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3" class="d-flex child-flex" v-for="item in items[0].productImages" :key="item.id" >
        <v-card class="mx-auto" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">  
          <v-img :src="item.image.url"></v-img>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```